# What does on_entry, from, event_args keys denote in ruby workflow?

Tags: ruby, workflow

Currently I am using Ruby 2.3 and trying to integrate state machine for my project.

If a state in my workflow model looks like:

```
      state :"pending" do
        on_entry do |from, *event_args|
          # perform some event
        end
      end
```

What do the keywords `on_entry`, `from`, `event_args` mean here?

Comment: This are not keywords. `on_entry` is a method, `from` and `*event_args` are parameters which the method provides when calling the block you provided there. The semenatics of this depends on the exact state machine gem you used there. Likely, the documentation of the gem will provide some examples and explanations of what the methods do.

Comment: In Ruby a comment is preceded by `'#'`, not `'//'`.